# Allocating memory for a double array using uint8_t

Tags: c, pointers, casting, malloc

I have a uint8_t array of memory allocated dynamically

```
uint8_t* array = malloc( sizeof( double ) * 100 );
```

I want to store doubles into the memory. Would this be considered defined behaviour, or is there some alignment issue I would have to worry about?

```
double* d = ( void* )array ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ )  
    d[i] = 3.1415 ;    //any double will do here
```

`d` should behave identically as if I would just allocate d as :

```
double* d = malloc( sizeof( double ) * 100 );
```

Also if I change the pointer array to point further into memory like this:

```
 double* d = ( void* )(array + sizeof( double ) * 50 ) ;
 for( int i = 0 ; i < 50; i++ )  
    d[i] = 3.1415 ;    //any double will do here
```

would the `d` behave identically as

```
double* d = malloc( sizeof( double ) * 50);
```

( how to correctly free the memory is not the issue here )

Comment: Why are you using `uint8_t*` rather than `double*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C standard guarantees that

> The  pointer  returned [by malloc] if  the allocation  succeeds  is  suitably
>   aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object
>   and then used to access  such  an  object  or an array of such objects
>   in the space allocated

in 7.20.3 "Memory management functions" [#1]

Your code is safe hence.

Comment: Cool, I had a moment of self doubt when coding that.

Comment: The current C11 standard has different wording: "The 
pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used
to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space
is explicitly deallocated)."

Comment: The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to malloc() is unspecified. The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds shall be suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly freed or reallocated).

Comment: @KeithThompson, Exactly!

Comment: @user1075375: If you're suggesting that this supports your comment that "It is only safe if `sizeof(double) == sizeof(double *)`", you're mistaken.

Comment: `2 * sizeof(double *)`, that was a mistake because word size on 32 bit ARM is 4 bytes whereas on x86 (which I haven't worked on lately) has a word size of 2 bytes. I had already updated my answer but forgot to change the comment here.

Comment: @user1075375: `sizeof (double*)` is not relevant, nor is "word size" (whatever that means). The C standard makes guarantees about the alignment of the pointer returned by `malloc`; those guarantees are the only thing that matters here. A pointer returned by `malloc` is properly aligned (referring to the alignment of the location it points to) for objects of type `double` -- or for *any* object type that doesn't have additional explicit alignment requirements (possible only in C11).

Comment: How is it not relevant ? malloc is defined to have alignment obligations upto 2*sizeof(void *) or so is what I have deduced from working on plethora of architectures.

Comment: @user1075375 As 32 bit x86 has no alignment constraints, C standard is still fulfilled when malloc() returns 8 byte aligned memory as described by the GNU libc doc.  You can access there a `long double` even when it is on an odd address.

Comment: @user1075375 although it does not matter here, but GNU libc's malloc() on x86 returns 16 byte aligned memory

Comment: @ensc, No it doesn't (on x86). "a multiple of 16 on 64-bit systems."

Comment: @ensc, Look at my answer, I explicitly stated that some architectures don't have an alignment requirement but C states that all variables must be at an address multiple of the size of their own types.

Comment: @user1075375: No, why would `long double` contradict anything? A pointer returned by `malloc` can point to a `long double`. The implementation must arrange for that pointer's alignment to be at least as strict as the alignment of `long double`. What conflict do you see? (And `long double` was introduced by the original ANSI C standard in 1989, or possibly earlier.)

Comment: @user1075375 read the source; glibc 2.18 returns memory aligned for `long double`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=5e419adac45f753c1079f55aa673fd65f512112e;hb=HEAD#l348

Comment: @ensc, That is exactly what I've been trying to say so far... `2 * SIZE_SZ` is the default alignment and on most machines sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void *) because pointer arithmatic is often used to obtain size of a block.

Comment: @user1075375 no; the default alignment in glibc is the max of `(2 * SIZE_SZ)` and `(__alignof__(long double))`. This matches the C standard.

Comment: exceptions where 2*size < alignof(long double) which I have already stated in the comments on my answer can exist and hence it is better to explicitly express alignment rather than relying on the implementation in client's libc.

Comment: @user1075375 can you point me please to the place in the C standard where it is stated that "that all variables must be at an address multiple of the size of their own types"?  I do not find such a thing and quick tests with gcc-4.8 show the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) defines malloc as returning a pointer sufficiently aligned for any type, double included, so it should work fine.

Comment: To be somewhat more precise, the `malloc` provided by the GNU requires 8 or 16 byte alignment, which is sufficient for 8-byte-sized `double`s.

Comment: The similar requirement in the ISO C standard is more relevant; it applies to *all* conforming C implementations, not just POSIX-conforming ones.

Comment: You're correct, but I just happened to have the GNU references up to verify before the ISO C ones.

Comment: The Open Group and GNU are two different things.

Comment: I double checked against both: [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html), [OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure GNU and the Open Group have requirements consistent with ISO C. But the question is about C; the OP didn't mention glibc or POSIX. If he's using Windows, for example, any guarantees made by GNU or POSIX are irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, I was being lazy, and happened to have the GNU references up already. Plus Microsoft's Visual Studio compiler/libraries haven't had the best record of complying to standards anyways so I figured I'd shoot for the most common (but incomplete) case.

Answer (score 0):

That initial "uint8_t *" will have no effect on the memory that is allocated. Once you have the address in a double pointer you should notice no difference.